# HDDs not detected on RS3UC080 SAS controller

Tags: hard-drive, detect

As per Title line:  I have 4 SAS 18TB new drives and an old SATA3 1TB seagate drive connected to the controller card. None are visible.
Fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop onto a 1TB NVMe boot/efi partition.
BIOS sees the card, Intel RAID Web Console sees the controller but says no HDDs connected.
VERY early in boot, the activity lights do flicker for the HDs connected to the card.
M/B BIOS and SAS card firmware fully updated.
dmesg sees the card.

I'm erally stumped as what to try next.

I'd be grateful for any ideas.

TIA,
Zoltan

Comment: There are some storage controllers on which you can't mix SATA and SAS drives. Make sure that your hardware works by connecting one drive at a time.

Comment: https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/76066/intel-raid-controller-rs3uc080.html

Answer (score 1):

This cotroller can :-)

I found the problem last night after banging my head for a few days.

I decided to open up the server box to slide out the M/B plate in order to connect up the rear backplane....... and I found that one of the 12v (yellow) molex pins had come out.

This will teach me rule #1:  Check all cables even when it is a major hassle to access them.

Thanks for your input.
Regards,
Zoltan